# Computer move to always random empty cell in tic tac toe game React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make tic tac toe in Javascript and I'm stuck at computer moves.

My game board is an empty array which I fill like this `board: new Array(9).fill("")`

Then for takin turns I making this

`board: state.board.map((item, index) => index === action.index ? item = action.player : item)`

So I'm mapping over board and checking if `index` of cell is equal to passed `index`. If it is I'm replacing empty space with `'X'` or `'O'` and if it is not it stays an empty cell.

My players turn function looks like this

```
userTurn (index) {
    if(this.props.gameFinished) {return}
    if(this.props.board[index] === '') {
        this.props.takeTurn(index, this.props.player);
        this.computerTurn();
    }
}
```

And my computer turn

```
computerTurn() {
     const randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

     if(this.props.board[randomNumber] === '') {
        this.props.takeTurn(randomNumber, this.props.computer);
      }
    }
```

In my computer turn function I'm not sure what to do when `this.props.board[randomNumber]` is  not empty string. Because if it is not empty right now nothing happens and computer doesn't place it's symbol on board.

So far I tried to add else statement like so

```
if(this.props.board[randomNumber] === '') {
            this.props.takeTurn(randomNumber, this.props.computer);
        } else {
            this.computerTurn();
        }
```

But sometimes it results in computer move placed on not empty cell somehow.

So the question is what is the way to place computer move on the game board?

Comment: It would be very helpful if we could see the code as a whole in codesendbox or jsfiddle. Also, you need to eliminate from your array the indexes that have been chosen by human player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a new array
2. Iterate through the board array and push the index of the empty cells to that array
3. Now that you have an array of empty cells, make the random number between 0 and the size of this array and now you guarantee that you will end up only with an empty cell

code :

```
computerTurn() {
    cells = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (this.props.board[i] === "") cells.push(i);
    }
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * cells.length);
    this.props.takeTurn(cells[randomNumber], this.props.computer);
  }
```

Comment: Tried it - sometimes still index in userTurn ends up the same as randomNumber in computerTurn and they clash.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out I think. Turns out that my `this.props.board` wasn't updated quick enough so when `computerTurn` run the `board` in `props` was 1 step behind from what was happening on the screen and in `userTurn` function. I did this `this.props.takeTurn(index, this.props.player).then(() =>{this.computerTurn(); });` and I think now it works